# SpringData JPA Methods or query to perform arithmetic operations with Postgres columns

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am a beginner with SpringBoot and accessing postgres table with multiple columns along with two timestamp with timezone columns (start time and end time). Besides retrieving all columns I also want to display time taken in seconds (end time - start time). I am extending PagingAndSortingRepository (findAll) for retrieving with paging and sorting. Please suggest the required solution. Will be using ReactJS for presentation.

Comment: as a general rule when asking a question, please present the code which you already tried, but failed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the presentation layer is important.

One way to have this implemented is to use a custom query something like:

```
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT id, column1, column2, (
           SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH from timezone1) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timezone2)
           FROM table where id = t.id) as difference
         FROM table t", nativeQuery = true)
  List<MyEntityProjection> findAllWithTimestamp();

}
```

`MyEntityProjection` is the projection interface containing getters of all fields plus getter for the second difference. If you want to learn more about projections, you can try [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

P.S. above query works in PostgreSQL only.

Comment: Thank You Turbut.  Will get back to you

Comment: Hi Turbut, couldn't resolve the issue. Have tried through various subquery, Lateral joins but either output don't show time_taken column or land up with error.

Comment: Please show your exact SQL, so I can give you an exact answer.